# complex query in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have three tables in mysql like this,

```
triz_sti

stu_id    name
-----------------
1          x1
2          x2


triz_sub

sub_id    sub_name
------------------
1          english
2          maths
3          science


triz

stu_id   sub_id   marks
-------------------------
1          1       23
1          2       56
1          3       83
2          1       78
2          2       23
2          3       50
```

i want the result like 
display all subject with higest mark in perticular subject with student name,

```
max_marks    sub_name     student_name
--------------------------------------
78            english     x2
56            maths       x1
83            science     x2
```

so please help for this output that i want, i have tried but i m not get it desire output.

Comment: Yeah, this looks suspiciously like a homework assignment.  Show us your query.  I will give you a hint: MAX() and JOIN.

Comment: @Riho Isn't the homework tag deprecated? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception/70233)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT 
  t.stu_id, t.sub_id, t.marks
FROM
triz t
JOIN (SELECT sub_id, MAX(marks) max_mark FROM triz GROUP BY sub_id) a ON (a.sub_id = t.sub_id AND a.max_mark = t.marks)
```

Of course you'll need to join it with lookup tables for names.

Have to say, it's early here so I might have missed something.

BR

Answer (score 0):

The general, simplified syntax in this case is

```
SELECT stuff FROM joined tables ORDER BY whatever
```

The easiest is the `ORDER BY`: you want to sort descending by marks, so you `ORDER BY marks DESC`.

Where do the data come from? From `triz`, joined to the others. So

```
triz JOIN triz_sti USING (stu_id) JOIN triz_sub USING (sub_id)
```

And you want to display the marks.

So you get

```
SELECT marks, sub_name, name AS student_name
    FROM triz JOIN triz_sti USING (stu_id) JOIN triz_sub USING (sub_id)
    ORDER BY marks DESC
```

.

The rest I leave to you. :-)